# My Python code will not run and I am not sure why, I have tried changing the kernel from 3.6 to 3.0

Tags: python, performance, azure, jupyter-notebook, kernel

My code will not run and i'm not sure whats wrong.

I have changed the kernel multiple times, but it is still not running.

**This is the addition function of a calculator**

```
def add(num1, num2):
    sum = num1 + num2
    return sum
```

**This is the subtraction function of a calculator**

```
def subtract(num1, num2):
    difference = num2 - num2
    return difference
```

**This is the multiplication function of a calculator**

```
def multiply(num1, num2):
    product = num1 * num2
    return product
```

**This is the division function of a calculator**

```
def divide(num1, num2):
    if num1 != 0:
        quotient = num2 / num1
        return quotient
    else:
        return 0

    num1 = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
    num2 = int(input("Please enter a second number:"))
    operator = input("What is your operation? Enter a + - * or / only.")

    if operator == "+":
        answer = add(num1, num2)

    elif operator == "-":
        answer = subtract(num1, num2)

    elif operator == "*":
        answer = multiply(num1, num2)

    elif operator == "/":
        answer = divide(num1, num2)

    else:
        print("This is not a valid operation!")
    print(str(answer))
```

I have not gotten any error messages at all. It just won't run.

Comment: What are you running though? These are all just individual functions that do nothing without being actually called

Comment: It seems either indentation is wrong or your are running everything inside the divide() function. You need to shift to left everything from the line num1 = ... for correct indentation.

Comment: What makes you think it is not running?

Answer (score 1):

Your print output was inside the division function.
You could do this as Short version:

```py
def calc(operator, x, y):
    return {
        '+': lambda: x + y,
        '-': lambda: x - y,
        '*': lambda: x * y,
        '/': lambda: x / y,
        }.get(operator, lambda: "This is not a valid operation!")()

num1 = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
num2 = int(input("Please enter a second number:"))
operator = input("What is your operation? Enter a + - * or / only.")
print(calc(operator, num1, num2))
```

Comment: Could you solve your problem or is anything unclear?

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you mistakenly put your "main" stuff (i.e the bit that actually controls 
 the flow your program) inside of your `divide(num1, num2)` function. Which is why when you run your program nothing seems to happen.

To fix it, try the following (note that indentation level!)

```
def add(num1, num2):
    sum = num1 + num2
    return sum

def subtract(num1, num2):
    difference = num2 - num2
    return difference

def multiply(num1, num2):
    product = num1 * num2
    return product

def divide(num1, num2):
    if num1 != 0:
        quotient = num2 / num1
        return quotient
    else:
        return 0

#Here is the code that actually runs the program, takes input, calls the functions, etc.
num1 = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
num2 = int(input("Please enter a second number:"))
operator = input("What is your operation? Enter a + - * or / only.")

if operator == "+":
    answer = add(num1, num2)

elif operator == "-":
    answer = subtract(num1, num2)

elif operator == "*":
    answer = multiply(num1, num2)

elif operator == "/":
    answer = divide(num1, num2)

else:
    print("This is not a valid operation!")
print(str(answer))
```